# Duplicate and redundant methods in Sheets Apps script API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

ref. to Google apps script:

Why does the *Sheet* object have these 2 methods: getName() & getSheetName(). They seem to be doing the exact same thing.

Secondly, why does the *SpreadSheet* object have the following methods at all: 
getSheetName()
getSheetId()

and other assoc. sheet methods like getLastRow(), etc.?

Ideally, the user should call getSheetByName(name) or getActiveSpreadsheet() and then use the above methods on the pointer returned. It doesn't make sense for the *SpreadSheet* object to directly have the above methods as those as for a *sheet* object.

Comment: The Apps Script documentation has a "Send Feedback" button at the top right of the window.  Stack Overflow is for evaluating code.  You could also use the [Google Apps Script Community Discussion](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a complaint/feedback for the external documentation author.

Answer (score 0):

1. They are the same (legacy maybe?)
2. By default the getSheetName on a spreadsheet object will get you the name of the first sheet, more often than not the only and main Sheet (somewhat useful)
   Same goes for the rest of the assoc methods.

   Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById("[id]").getSheetName());
      Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById("[id]").getSheets()[0].getSheetName());
      Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById("[id]").getRange("A1").getValue());

All point to the same first and "default" sheet

Comment: Well nowhere is it mentioned in the official documentation that it picks the first sheet. It's ambiguous and Google should just remove it.

Comment: I figure since Apps Script is not only for developers but for the "general public" they decided to keep it.

Comment: I'd vote for too many methods rather than too few and I really love the organization of the online documentation.